# Can we find the CDF of the following expression?

Tags: probability-theory

Can we find the CDF of the random variable
where 
$$\gamma = \frac{a_1\, g}{a_2 \, g +1}+  \frac{b_1\, h}{b_2 \, h +1},$$

where $g$ and $h$ are independent exponential random variables with different parameters and $a_1, a_2,b_1,b_2$ are positive numbers less than $1$? Also: $a_1 + a_2 =1$ and $b_1 + b_2 =1$.

In other words, I need to find:

$$F_{\gamma}(x) = P(\gamma <x)$$

Comment: Are $g$ and $h$ independent? Are they characterized by the same parameter or not?

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: I guess you need a numerical resource.

Answer (score 0):

Let
$$\begin{align}
G &\sim \mathsf{Exp}(\lambda)\\
H &\sim \mathsf{Exp}(\mu)\\
\gamma &\sim \frac{a_1 G}{a_2 G +1}+  \frac{b_1 H}{b_2 H +1},
\end{align}$$
with $\lambda,\mu > 0$, $a_\star, b_\star > 0$ and $a_1 + a_2 = b_1 + b_2 = 1$.

Then
$$F_\gamma(x) = \mathsf P(\gamma \le x) = \int_0^{+\infty} \mathsf P(\gamma \le x \mid H = h) f_H(h)\,\mathrm dh,$$
where $f_H$ is the PDF of $H$, that is
$$f_H(h) = \mu e^{-\mu h}.$$

Through simple algebra, we find that
$$\mathsf P(\gamma \le x \mid H = h) = \mathsf P\left(G \le \frac{y}{a_1 - a_2 y}\right) = F_G\left(\frac{y}{a_1 - a_2 y}\right),$$
where
$$y = x - \frac{b_1 h}{b_2 h + 1}$$
and $F_G$ is the CDF of $G$.

Therefore,
$$\begin{align}
F_\gamma(x) &= \int_0^{+\infty} F_G\left(\frac{y}{a_1 - a_2y}\right)f_H(h)\,\mathrm dh =\\[1ex]
&= \int_0^{+\infty} \left[1 - \exp\left(-\frac{y\lambda}{a_1 - a_2y}\right)\right]\mu e^{-\mu h}\,\mathrm dh =\\
&= 1 -\mu \int_0^{+\infty} \exp\left(-\frac{y\lambda}{a_1 - a_2y} - \mu h\right)\mathrm dh
\end{align}$$

Maybe this integral has a closed form, but I wasn't able to find it. I asked a new question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2779243/closed-form-for-the-improper-integral-int-0-infty-exp-left-fracy-lambd) in case someone has an idea.