# Closed form for the improper integral $\int_0^{+\infty} \exp\left(-\frac{y\lambda}{a_1 - a_2y} - \mu h\right)\mathrm dh$

Tags: calculus, integration, probability-theory, improper-integrals

I encountered this integral in an answer of mine ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2778124/can-we-find-the-cdf-of-the-following-exprerssion/2778522#2778522)), but I wasn't able to find a closed form.

In detail, the integral is
$$F_\gamma(x) = \int_0^{+\infty} \exp\left(-\frac{y\lambda}{a_1 - a_2y} - \mu h\right)\mathrm dh$$
where
$$y = x - \frac{b_1 h}{b_2 h + 1}$$
and $\lambda, \mu, a_1, a_2, b_1, b_2 > 0$ with $a_1 + a_2 = b_1 + b_2 = 1$.

For context, the function $F_\gamma$ is the CDF of the random variable $\gamma$ (defined in the linked thread). From some simulations, it would seem that $\gamma$ behaves like a gamma distribution, so maybe this could be used to find a simpler form for $F_\gamma$ or its derivative $F'_\gamma(x)$ (to compare it to the PDF of the gamma distribution).

I was wondering if some progress can be made towards a simpler form for the random variable $\gamma$.

Comment: I haven't checked all the details to see if it works here, but you might want to try using Glasser's Master Theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glasser's_master_theorem.

Comment: @Tom Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm having a hard time understanding how it could be useful in this case. As I understand it, I should express the argument of the exponential as a series. Is that right?

Comment: Just as a sum, but yeah. However, looking at the form of $y$ again, it seems that it won't work, sadly.

Comment: I doubt there's a closed form for the define integral.